Need Find a String array in a table on SQLlite
I Need Find a String array in a table SQLite
The Table
Product
---------
Description

I have a TextBox (Entry) of filter in a page of MAUI, this field it's the filter for find products in the table.
For example: filter = "Tires GoodYear"
In SQL the query is:
select * from Product where Description like '%Tires%' OR Description like '%GoodYear%'

The string array can be of n items
I tried this:
var words = new string[] { "word1", "word2", "word3" };
var query = dbContext.Product.Where(e => words.Any(p => e.Description.Contains(p))).ToList();

But I get exception in run time: "Cannot compile: Lambda"
I want do it in my project MAUI with Entity Framework

Does this answer your question? How dynamic or usage in EF Core Where?

You may also refer to Getting Started with EF Core and Xamarin since the doc also applies to MAUI.

Here is another way to store and retrieve information in a local database, .NET MAUI local databases
